# If $b^2|c^3$, then $b|c$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

> Prove or disprove using a counter example: If $b^2 \vert c^3$, then $b \vert c$

I am having a hard time approaching these as other questions are either number specific or variable and number. Any help would be appreciated. I need to state if it is true or false. If false give an example which makes it so.

Comment: Do you think it is true or not? Have you tried lots of examples?

Comment: For even number it works, but for odd is does not. I want to give a formal counter example but do not know how to go about it.

Comment: A counterexample is a counterexample: do you have a b and a c for which $b^2$ divides $c^3$ but $b$ does not divide $c$? Then, state them, and you've got it.

Comment: @MatthewConroy well a poster below pretty much gave me it. So for instance if I had another question if $19|x^2, then 19|x.  A simple counter example would work just as nicely. However, in this example 19 will divide factors of itself. so 38 works 57 and so forth but it breaks in all other cases.  So it is true, not false. Now I need to give a formal proof.

Comment: True if $\gcd(b,c)=1$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$8^2=64$ and $4^3=64$
So $8^2\mid4^3$ but obviously $8\not\mid 4$

Answer (score 2):

Any integer $c$ has a unique prime number factorization
$$
c = s \prod_{k=1}^\infty p_k^{i_k}
$$
where $s \in \{-1,1\}$, $i_k \in \mathbb{N}_0$, $p_k \in \mathbb{P}$ thus
$$
c^3 = s \prod_{k=1}^\infty p_k^{3i_k}
$$
similar
$$
b = t \prod_{k=1}^\infty p_k^{j_k} \\
b^2 = \prod_{k=1}^\infty p_k^{2j_k}
$$
Now $b^2 \vert c^3$ means
$$
2 j_k \le 3 i_k \quad (k \in \mathbb{N}) \quad (*)
$$
and $b \vert c$ means
$$
j_k \le i_k \quad (k \in \mathbb{N}) \quad (**)
$$
We notice that the inequalities $(*)$ and $(**)$ are not equivalent.

E.g. $j_1 = 3$ and $i_1 = 2$, as in $b=2^3=8$ and $c=2^2=4$ satisfy $(*)$, but will violate $(**)$.

This would be the example $8^2 \vert 4^3 \iff 64 \vert 64$ (which is true) vs $8 \vert 4$ (which is false).